# What is the meaning of "little long-term " in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> Many such drives from the government have been initiated with little long-term results.

I know the meaning of long-term.But what it means when "little" word is added before it?

## TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Little' here applies to "long-term results", and not just to "long-term".

Hence, what it means is that the drives from the government have been started with a very few (positive) results in the longer run.